# memory Error while training word2vec: hierarchical softmax

Tags: parameters, word2vec

I am training word embeddings with word2vec and with some Parameter configurations I Always get a Memory error. I do this for the whole english Wikipedia and using PathLineSentence for the Input (more than 11 GB). I do not really know, which Parameter Setting is wrong, but I see a trend: When hierachical softmax is set to 1 I get an error - so what is the Default value of hs - 0 or 1? Is it also possible to do hs and negative sampling?

It would be great when you please help me with my Questions and what I can do to handle my Problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would typically only want to do negative-sampling or hierarchical-softmax, not both.

The default is negative-sampling, equivalent to if you explicitly specified `negative=5, hs=0`. If you enable hierarchical-softmax, you should disable negative-sampling, for example: `hs=1, negative=0`.

If you're getting a memory error, the most common causes (if you otherwise have a reasonable amount of RAM) are:

- attempts to load an entire larger-than-practical corpus into memory. However, if you're using a good corpus iterator, like `PathLineSentence`, properly, it will only read data from files as needed
- trying to create a model that's too large - with the largest contributors to model size being the size of the known vocabulary and the vector-size chosen. If I recall correctly, for something like Wikipedia, you can set `min_count=100` and still wind up with a vocabulary of around 1 million words. With 300-dimensional vectors, that'd require (1 million * 300 dimensions * 4 bytes-per-dimension=) 1.2GB just for the word-vectors, and about that much again for the model's internal weights, and then some smaller amounts of memory for other structures.

So to address memory problems, consider: (1) get more RAM; (2) ensure the corpus is only being streamed; (3) reduce vector-size; (4) reduce the trained-vocabulary, most commonly by using a larger `min_count` cutoff to discard rarer words.

Comment: Thank you very much! So do you mean when I do not explicit specify the Parameters e.g. just call model = Word2Vec(sentences, size=100) that I do not use hierachical softmax (hs=0)?

Comment: Yes. You can see all the defaults which apply, if you don't specify other values, in the `gensim` docs for the `Word2Vec` class instantiation method: https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html#gensim.models.word2vec.Word2Vec